# Extending the Range

Tags: vba, excel

Below is a code to merge multiple workbooks into a single workbook. However, the files that are being extracted from the local folder comes up incomplete once the process is done. My guess is the workbooks/files in that local folder far exceeds the range that's in the code.

How do I extend the range, preferably "unlimited" or to the maximum limit of excel to transfer and combine the workbooks as much as possible?

Below is the code that I use.

Please advise and our help is much appreciated.

Vincent

```
Sub Merger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\856")

Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "extend the range".  Are these all `.xls` workbooks?

Comment: They're all csv/flat files. And range, I mean the limit to where the maximum of files can be merged/transferred into a single workbook. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What specific problem have you run into?

Comment: I'm running to an incomplete data. My thinking is, maybe it's because the files in my local folder far exceed the the range of columns and/or rows.

Comment: Excel can handle a little more than `1,000,000` rows.  You are only referencing a small fraction of that `65,536`.  Why not reference the entire column?

Comment: I've actually did reference the column to ("A1000000") but to no avail. It's not gathering/merging all the data that's on my local folder. Local folder contains 5000+ files. When everything is merged, it only gathered 2000+ files. I did a spot check by reducing the number of files in half in my local folder, and came out perfectly.

Comment: How many rows of data do you have, roughly?

Comment: Also, how many files are there in `filesObj` after you `Set filesObj = dirObj.Files`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171650/discussion-between-vincent-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Answer (score 0):

Going to take a guess and say that you're looking for two dynamic ranges for a copy and a paste:

```
dim lrs as long, lrd as long 'last row source/destination
'could also look for last column dynamically

'inside of your loop
with everyObj.sheets("")
    lrs = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
    .range(.cells(1,1),.cells(lrs,"iv").copy
end with
with thisworkbook.sheets("")
    lrd = .cells(.rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
    .range(.cells(lrd+1,1),.cells(lrd+1+lrs,"iv").paste
end with
```

untested code, giving a shot in the dark.  you should be able to add nearly unlimited lines into excel, provided you're using the correct code to get there.

i would recommend closing each source file and specify to NOT SAVE (the latter appears missing from your code).

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the last row or end of the range, try this:

```
Sub Merger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\856")

Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

' find last row in column A
Dim last_row As Long
With ActiveSheet
    last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Range("A2:IV" & Range("A" & last_row).End(xlUp).Row).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

Range("A" & last_row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the outcome is the same as my original code. I'd like to point out that if the files in my local folder 
 ("C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\856") over 3,000 files, that's the time I run into getting an incomplete data when ran. I'm wondering if there are limitations to the Range code? Or if the files are trying to merge but won't copy?

Answer (score 0):

`Range().Rows.Count` should be used of hard coding the last row.  All referencing inside the range should be fully qualified (reference the source worksheet).  Using a `With WorkBook.Worksheet` block will ensure that you return the proper Range everytime.

> ```
> With bookList.Worksheets(1)
>     .Range("A2:IV2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
> End With
> ```

`Range.Copy` should only be used when you need to include Formatting.  `Range.Value` returns an Array of values from the Range.

`Application.DisplayAlerts = False` should precede `bookList.Close`.  Using the `Workbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` is preferable and eliminates the need to disable `DisplayAlerts` (e.g.  `bookList.Close SaveChanges:=False`)

```
Sub Merger()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\856")

    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

        With bookList.Worksheets(1)
            Set Source = .Range("A2:IV2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        End With

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
            Set Target = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End With

        Target.Resize(Source.Rows.Count, Source.Columns.Count).Value = Source.Value

        bookList.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

### Addendum

The current "Range Limit" is `1048576 Rows x 16384 Columns`.  This code extends the Range from `A2:V2` to the last used cell in `Column A` of the CSV File. If the data in `Column A` does not extend to the end of the list change `.Range("A"` to the appropriate column.

> ```
> Set Source = .Range("A2:IV2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
> ```

You should set a breakpoint at `bookList.Close` and test the Ranges.

`Immediate Window`

> ?Source.Address, Target.Resize(Source.Rows.Count, Source.Columns.Count).Address

[image: Immediate Window]

Comment: I've tried this, but the outcome is the same as my original code. I'd like to point out that if the files in my local folder 
 ("C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\856") over 3,000 files, that's the time I run into getting an incomplete data when ran. I'm wondering if there are limitations to the Range code? Or if the files are trying to merge but won't copy?

Comment: @Vincent I edited my post to describe how to troubleshoot the code.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Merger()
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Dim targetSht As Worksheet

    Set targetSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\856")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj
        Select Case mergeObj.GetExtensionName(everyObj)
            Case "csv" ' handle only "csv" files (you can extend the list of allowed extensions)
                With Workbooks.Open(everyObj).Worksheets(1) ' open current file as a workbook and reference its first worksheet 
                    With Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)) ' reference referenced worksheet "used" range except its first row
                        If targetSht.UsedRange.Rows(targetSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + .Rows.Count <= targetSht.Rows.Count Then ' if target sheet has room for current file rows 
                            .Copy targetSht.Cells(targetSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                        Else
                            MsgBox "not enough room in " & targetSht.Name & " for " & everyObj.Name
                        End If
                    End With
                    .Parent.Close False
                End With
        End Select
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Vincent, any feedback?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I'm running into "run-time error 1004". Also got an error that I need to switch to 64 bit microsoft office. I check the version that I have and I do have the 64 bit. An error also stated that memory is insufficient. I checked my RAM and I do have 16gb.

Comment: which line is highlighted when hitting "run-time error 1004"?